# Elasticsearch Update with Versioning - NEST/C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am looking to implement Elastic search versioning feature to update records using NEST library and C#. I am actually looking to create a helper which does the following:

1. Read the existing record.
2. Make changes to the record.
3. Update document using version feature.

I have done some of my research and didn`t find information I am looking for. Can anyone point me some code examples, implementation or tests?

Comment: I wrote a blog post a couple of years ago about Optimistic Concurrency control with ES and NEST: http://forloop.co.uk/blog/optimistic-concurrency-with-elasticsearch-and-nest it uses Elasticsearch 1.x and NEST 1.x but it's fundamentally the same in 2.x and 5.x

Comment: It gives me a clear context on how to implement the functionality. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi @RussCam, In your post I noticed that you use ElasticsearchServerException object to catch and handle the retry. For some reason I am unable to access this object in my code. I see ElasticsearchClientException. Can you point how to access the server exception?

Answer (score 2):

I use the following class which includes versioning `Update`

```
public class SampleElasticClient
{
    private const string VERSION_CONFLICT_ERROR = "version_conflict_engine_exception";

    protected readonly string IndexName;

    protected readonly ElasticClient Client;

    public SampleElasticClient(Uri uri, string indexName)
    {
        Client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(uri).DefaultIndex(indexName));
        IndexName = indexName;
    }

    public IGetResponse<T> Get<T>(Id id) where T : class
    {
        var request = new GetRequest<T>(IndexName, typeof(T), id);
        var response = Client.Get<T>(request);
        EnsureSuccessResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    public void Update<T>(Id id, Func<T, T> update, int retriesCount = 10) where T : class
    {
        Retry(() =>
        {
            var getResponse = Get<T>(id);
            var item = update(getResponse.Source);
            return Client.Index(item, index => getResponse.Found
                ? index.Version(getResponse.Version)
                : index.OpType(OpType.Create));
        }, retriesCount);
    }

    protected void EnsureSuccessResponse(IResponse response)
    {
        if (!response.IsValid && response.ApiCall.HttpStatusCode != 404)
        {
            var errorMessage = response.ServerError != null
                ? $"ElasticSearch error: {response.ServerError.Error}\r\n" +
                               $"Http status: {response.ServerError.Status}"
                : $"ElasticSearch error. {response.DebugInformation}";
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    protected void Retry(Func<IResponse> execute, int retriesCount)
    {
        var numberOfRetry = 0;
        do
        {
            var response = execute();
            if (response.ServerError?.Error.Type != VERSION_CONFLICT_ERROR || ++numberOfRetry == retriesCount)
            {
                EnsureSuccessResponse(response);
                return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

The `Retry` method responsible for handling `version_conflict_engine_exception` and retrying update. `Update` method enther inserts or updates entity using lambda to handle entity retrieved from index. Here is an example of using this class

```
var client = new SampleElasticClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"), indexName);
var id = 123;
client.Update<Sample>(id, entity =>
{
    if (entity == null)
        entity = new Sample { Id = id }; // Or any other action for new entity

    entity.MyField = "new value";
    return entity;
});
```